# How do I write this GROUP BY query in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose I have a column called "fruits"
I want to select all of the top fruits, ranked by fruits (and group by + count).

```
Fruits:
orange
orange
apple
banana
apple
apple
```

In this case, the select statement would return:

```
apple, 3
orange, 2
banana, 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select fruits, count(fruits)
from table
group by fruits
order by count(fruits) desc
```

Answer (score 4):

Untested:

```
SELECT 
   fruit_name, 
   COUNT(fruit_id)
FROM
   fruit
GROUP BY
   fruit_name
ORDER BY
   COUNT(fruit_id) DESC
```

Comment: @Phil, this looks great. Be sure to use `fruit_name ASC` for the secondary order.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT fruitname, COUNT(*) AS ttl
FROM fruits 
GROUP BY fruitname 
ORDER BY ttl DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested:

```
select fruits, count(fruits)
from fruit
group by fruits
order by 2 desc
```